# .NET Collection only in VB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, collections

Why is the `Collection` in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` library?  Why is it not in a more general location.  Is there a reason Microsoft "hid" it from C#?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y8b3b3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Isn't it Microsoft.VisualBasic? There is no System.VisualBasic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Collection` in the Microsoft.VisualBasic library is a throw-back to the older VB6 Collection.

There is a `System.Collection` namespace that you should probably look into for the basic .NET collection functionality you probably want.

Also, it's kind of worth mentioning that you *CAN* add a reference and make use of the System.VisualBasic namespace in your C# code.  It's just that, most of the time, there isn't any need to do it (example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173136.aspx).

EDIT - Updated namespace - sorry!

Comment: From the MSDN: "Although the Visual Basic Collection object has functionality identical to the Collection object in Visual Basic 6.0, the two cannot interoperate in a COM environment."

Answer (score 2):

It is intended for backwards compatibility with VB6.  You should not use it, if possible, for new code.  `List(Of T)` would be the preferred general purpose collection.

Comment: The `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` class has some features which were for years not available in any other Framework classes, such as the ability to conditionally remove items while enumerating.

Comment: I'm not sure if the backwards-compatibility statement is true - from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.collection?view=netframework-4.8#remarks it says "Although the Visual Basic Collection object has functionality identical to the Collection object in Visual Basic 6.0, the two cannot interoperate in a COM environment."

Answer (score 1):

It's a functional equivalent to the `Collection` class from VB6.  It's there just to ease porting of VB6 code; for anything new you should use the normal .NET collection classes.